# H1 tag overflow the image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When window is in full screen it shows like this:

[image: When window is in full screen it shows like this]

When I tried to make it mobile friendly or window shrink the h1 tag is overflow the image:

[image: When I tried to make it mobile friendly or window shrink the h1 tag is overflow the image]

I also tried with overflow property but it didn't work. Also I want that my h1 and img must that particular position which one I did but also want it must be mobile friendly. If there any CSS or JavaScript I need to use, please suggest it.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>test video</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Butcherman&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">


    <style type="text/css">
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
}
#stripe img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 40%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 5px;
    overflow: inherit;
}
h1{
    position: fixed;
    left: 45%;
    top: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Butcherman', cursive;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center; 
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: inherit;
}
#stripe{
    position : relative;
    background: #404040;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    right: 0;
}
    </style>

</head>
<body>

     <div id="stripe">
        <img src="logo/mask.png">
        <h1>My Website</h1>               
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `position: flxed` on `img`

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle for us please this is a lot of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've solved my problem with this CSS:

```
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
}
#stripe img{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-right: 0;
}
h1{
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Butcherman', cursive;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

img + h1{
    display: inline-block;
}
#stripe{
    position: relative;
    background: #404040;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>test video</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Butcherman&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">


    <style type="text/css">
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
}
#stripe img{
    display: inline-block;
}
h1{
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Butcherman', cursive;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center; 
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
}
#stripe{
    background: #404040;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
    </style>

</head>
<body>

     <div id="stripe">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
          <h1>My Website</h1> 
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your answer nothing is showing but i solved it almost similar but i changing minor of things thanks giving suggestion display: inline-block;

Comment: Also i m posting my answer thanks again Delwor Hosain

Answer (score 0):

I think You should add the following CSS to your `div` and `img` styles.

```
#stripe{    
    position: relative;
}

#stripe img{
    position: absolute;
}
```

and you not need to give `h1` tag `position: fixed` style. remove it.

Comment: I tried as your answer but it still overflow the image

Comment: did you also try removing *h1* tag position style?

Comment: I think the problem is in *text-align : center*  which you are using in div( #stripe) CSS. so try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to consider using flexboxes:

```css
#stripe {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  background: #404040;
  color: white;
  height: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="stripe">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/15/21/38/skull-35404_960_720.png" />
  <h1>Someone's Website</h1>
</div>
```